# Python unit test. How to add some sleeping time between test cases?

Tags: python, unit-testing

I am using python unit test module. I am wondering is there anyway to add some delay between every 2 test cases? Because my unit test is just making http request and I guess the server may block the frequent request from the same ip.

Comment: A test that depends on a real live HTTP server isn't what most people would call a unit test. Generally for unit tests you mock server behavior so you don't have a dependency where you *need* to sleep.

It's still useful to know how to do this in order to write integration tests, though.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Put a sleep inside the `tearDown` method of your `TestCase`

```
import time

class ExampleTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def tearDown(self):
        time.sleep(1)  # sleep time in seconds
```

`tearDown()` will be executed after every test within that `TestCase` class.

The modules documentation can be found [here](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html).

Comment: Just for clarification, I did it in the `tearDown` instead of `setUp` because it said "between" and that automatically made me think that it was desirable that the first one run immediately (which in this case is unclear).  If it didn't matter about the delay being before or after the first test, putting it in `setUp` and leaving `tearDown` out would work just fine as well.

Comment: In my humble opinion there is no need to explicitly define/override the `setUp()` method because the `unittest.TestCase` class already provides the method stub ([source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/deae6b451fefd5fd3143dd65051e1d341e5a5f84/Lib/unittest/case.py#L453)), so you could remove this from your answer but you should add the line `import time`.

Answer (score 3):

```
import time
time.sleep(2.5) # sleeps for 2.5 seconds
```

You might want to consider making the delay a random value between x and y.

Comment: you mean i have to put this after every test case? Is there any universal settings i can use to achieve the same thing?

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing your code... but you probably could make all your test cases inherit from one common testcase which provides a `def setUp(self):` method which does the `time.sleep` call.